# MySQL 2 tables combine with foreign key - See entries with specific function

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have 2 tables - the first table has an ID with name and function. The second table has a date and the ID from the first table.

Table 1:

```
ID | name | func1 | func2
1  | stef | 1     | 1
2  | rob  | 0     | 1
3  | bob  | 0     | 0
4  | isa  | 1     | 0
```

Table 2:

```
date       | ID
2020-05-01 | 2
2020-05-01 | 4
2020-05-01 | 3
```

Now I need these IDs from table 2, which have a 1 at "func1". So in this case the ID 1 and 4.

How do I get these?
I tried a lot with MySQL, but didn't find a solution. Only errors.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query needs a join, as shown below:

```
select b.ID
from table1 a
join table2 b on b.ID = a.ID
where a.func1 = 1
```

However this query will find only `4` and not `1`, since the latter does not exist in Table 1.